# Which is from this queries is more faster

Tags: wp-query, performance

I need to do some query. Now i choosing from this variables. Which is from this queries is more faster. Which differences between them ?

```
function filter_where($where = '') {
     $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-10 days')) . "'";
     return $where;
} 

add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
$my_query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'post_views', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
```

And this.

```
 function filter_where($where = '') {
      $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-10 days')) . "'";
      return $where;
}

add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$my_query = new WP_Query( "meta_key=post_views&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&posts_per_page=5&paged=$paged" );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These queries are the same - the only difference being the syntax. There'll be no noticeable performance difference. I prefer the first for readability when it is formatted correctly.

(Also, the first query doesn't use the `paged` argument, so it won't 'paginate' - but I guess that was omitted by mistake).